# Calculating difference and adding new column for every two columns in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
library(data.table)
> dt1
   id i i-2015 a a-2015 w w-2015 f f-2015
1:  A 2      1 1      1 2      2 2      1
2:  B 4      2 2      1 3      1 3      3
3:  C 6      6 3      1 4      2 5      1

dt1 <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C"), i = c(2, 4, 6), `i-2015` = c(1, 
2, 6), a = c(1, 2, 3), `a-2015` = c(1, 1, 1), w = c(2, 3, 4), 
    `w-2015` = c(2, 1, 2), f = c(2, 3, 5), `f-2015` = c(1, 3, 
    1)), .Names = c("id", "i", "i-2015", "a", "a-2015", "w", 
"w-2015", "f", "f-2015"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

What I would like to achieve is at every two columns to add a new one calculating the difference between the two columns before like this:

```
> result
   id i i-2015 i difference a a-2015 a difference w w-2015 w difference f f-2015 f difference
1:  A 2      1            1 1      1            0 2      2            0 2      1            1
2:  B 4      2            2 2      1            1 3      1            2 3      3            0
3:  C 6      6            0 3      1            2 4      2            2 5      1            4
```

What I tried to do is the following, first find the columns for which I would need to add the difference and then use add_column to specify:

```
library(tibble)
diff_columns <- unique(str_replace(names(dt1), "-2015", ""))[-1]
for (i in 1:length(diff_columns)) {

   assign(paste(diff_columns[i], "difference"), dt1[, get(diff_columns[i]) - get(paste0(diff_columns[i], "-2015"))])
   dt1 <- add_column(dt1, get(paste(diff_columns[i], "difference")), .after = paste0(diff_columns[i], "-2015"))
  }
```

But this fails in many different ways...

First of all the `dt1[, get(diff_columns[i]) - get(paste0(diff_columns[i], "-2015"))]` does not get me what I want and I have no clue why. 
The  `dt1[, get(diff_columns[i])]` part works as expected but not the `dt1[get(paste0(diff_columns[i], "-2015"))]` part.

And second the add_column part does not evaluate the paste(diff_columns[i], "difference") and tries to use this as the column name, which does not work as there cannot be duplicated column names.

Comment: If you sanitize your data, it's considerably easier. Something like `melt(dt1, id="id", meas = patterns("^\\w$", "^\\w-\\d{4}$"), value.name=c("letter", "yr"), variable.factor=FALSE)[.(v = as.character(1:4), r = c("i", "a","w", "f")), on=.(variable=v), variable := i.r ][]`, after which you'd want to only go back to the unworkable wide format when publishing, I guess.

Comment: Yeah probably you are right. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
m1 <- do.call(cbind, Map(cbind, dt1[, 2:(ncol(dt1)-1)], 
    dt1[, 3:ncol(dt1)], dt1[, 2:(ncol(dt1)-1)] - dt1[, 3:ncol(dt1)]))
```

Comment: Thank you. The result is not exactly what I would like, column 4 has values 1,2,6 while theoretically (if I understand this correctly) it should have the values of the column a in dt1 so 1,2,3. Moreover the result has 21 columns, something is not right...